# How do I draw multiple objects in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw two separate objects so that I can perform a query while drawing the second object. The drawing code will look something like this:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,...);  // draw first object

glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, queries[0]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,...);  // draw second object

glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED);

glGetQueryObjectiv(queries[0], GL_QUERY_RESULT, &result);

return restult;
```

Most OpenGL tutorials don't go beyond a single `glDraw*()` command. As I understand it from [this site](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html) I need two Vertex Array Objects, but the site doesn't explain how to set the Buffer Data for the separate objects. For the sake of simplicity, let's just say I want the objects to be a single triangle each:

```
Triangle1:
vertex1: -0.5, 0.0, 0.0
vertex2: -0.5, 0.5, 0.0
vertex3:  0.0, 0.0, 0.0

Triangle2:
vertex1: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
vertex2: 0.5, 0.5, 0.0
vertex3: 0.5, 0.0, 0.0
```

Can someone show me how to setup the Vertex Array Objects, Vertex Buffer Objects, and Element Array Buffers to perform this query in C++ and OpenGL 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for drawing geometry misses two essential steps:

1. creation of the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER (glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData)
2. association of drawing state machine with the array buffer (calls to gl…Pointer functions)

It is those which allow drawing multiple meshes.

Comment: So do I need to create a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER as well as setting each glVertexAtribPointer before each glDraw* command? Do I need another Vertex Array Object, too?

Comment: @NealKruis: You can either re-set gl…Pointers before each draw call, or you can adjust the base index, or you just make the draw call make use only a subset of the element index array buffer. Vertex Array Objects are containers for gl…Pointer bindings, so you normally either gl…Pointer binding calls, or you use multiple VAOs; you rarely mix them.

Answer (score -2):

A couple of suggestions:

You can draw one collection of triangles that aren't connected to each other and appear to be two objects visually.

You can also create two separate OpenGL contexts. One context for each of the objects you want to draw. When drawing each object make the associated context the 'current' context and make your draw calls.

Comment: The query only works if they are drawn separately (they can't be drawn at the same time as one collection). It is also important that the triangles be drawn together, because I want to know if there are pixels missing because one triangle overlaps the other.

Comment: Multiple OpenGL contexts for multiple objects? WTF?! No! Don't do this! In general you want to create only one OpenGL context and work with just that if possible. -1 for such misguiding information.

Comment: @datenwolf So why would using a feature provided by the API be bad?

Comment: @Jay: Just because it's there it means that it does what you wish it to do, or that you should use it at all: Multiple OpenGL contexts are used to separate state machines, for example if you have plugin drawing some overlay into the main window, and want to prevent the plugin in to clobber the main context. I think you misunderstood what nails this hammer (multiple OpenGL contexts) is supposed to hit.

Comment: @datenwolf So why is drawing two separate objects, at separate times, not a reason to have a separate state? This seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Jay: Because switching contexts is **EXPENSIVE**. And say you have to separate objects, the chances are very high, that the OpenGL state required to draw them is practically identical for both of them. Most likely the projection, the viewport, the illumination setup (light positions and colors), the viewpoint will be identical. In fact it's recommended practice to sort object drawing in a way, that it minimizes the number of state changes. Switching context is kind of the nuclear kind of state change, something you'd want to avoid at all costs.

Comment: @Jay: There's actually only one reason to use separated OpenGL contexts: If your OpenGL code has to collaborate with some other OpenGL code which is a black box to you. Then you use a different OpenGL context to avoid breaking the other parts of the program.

Comment: @Jay: To give you another perspective: Each OpenGL contexts consumes a whole OS handle object. OS handles are heavyweight. Managing individual objects by utilizing individual OpenGL contexts was as if you'd write text putting each single word into an own individual file and then chain those files together with includes or similar.